# Error loading type library/DLL (TeeChart.TChart.10)

Tags: teechart, apimonitor, dolphin-smalltalk

We had no problem with an older version (TeeChart.TChart.7) but recently we installed TeeChart.TChart.10 and started to have an issue in our runtime application. Our problem is that whenever we click in any TeeChartView in the application there is a pop-up window [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqjKx.png) with the following text: "Error loading type library/DLL".

Our application is developed in Dolphin Smalltalk and we never had problems before, or while in develpment environment this issue does not exist, but it appears in the runtime application. We can provide more information about the error if you want, we tried logging the API calls with API Monitor v2 32-bit, but the error is not very descriptive.

We hope you can help us, otherwise we will have to downgrade to the previous version we were using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error loading dll may suggest a problem with registration of the TeeChart ocx in the runtime environment. Are you able to cross-check that by running a small VB app that uses TeeChart or similar in the runtime machine?

Comment: I tried adding some TeeChart components in an Excel worksheet just to see if it throws the same exception, but it works fine in Excel.

Comment: Can you please try to reduce the application to a simple test example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here?

Comment: Hi Yeray first of all, tanks for your soon reply, i'm copying a link here with a very simple application to reproduce the problem. Just run the app and click inside. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzHYBYg21Efobl9mdGZXRmFybWs

Comment: Hi Marc, Yeray, could you see the file I sent to you? We are in a bit of a hurry but it's ok we can wait a little more, anyways we can always downgrade to the previous version.

Comment: Thanks, we've been able to download the file and can run to test. We may need some more information at some stage but for the moment we can make initial checks with this.

Comment: Yes of course you can ask for any information, we are very thankful for your help, and we stay alert for any answer you can give us, because of what I previously mentioned that we are about to release a new version of our software and we wanted to release it with the newest TeeChart version.

Comment: We have a fix version available for you to test if you can get your contact info to us via email : info (at) steema.com